# How to create a unit test with F# (using MSTest)

Tags: unit-testing, f#

I am trying to learn F# via TDD.

However, I am struggling to write my first test:

```
module MSTest
    open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

    [<TestClass>] type CalculatorShould () = 
        [<TestMethod>] member this.''add 1 and 2 with result of 3'' () = Assert.AreEqual(3, 1 + 2)
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

I receive the following errors:

> Error     A type definition requires one or more members or other
>   declarations. If you intend to define an empty class, struct or
>   interface, then use 'type ... = class end', 'interface end' or 'struct
>   end'.
>
> Error     Unexpected quote symbol in member definition. Expected
>   identifier, '(', '(*)' or other token.
>
> Error     'get' and/or 'set' required c:\Users\Bizmonger\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2015\Projects\FSharpModel\Tests_MyTest.fs 5 Error     This is not
>   a valid numeric literal. Sample formats include 4, 0x4, 0b0100, 4L,
>   4UL, 4u, 4s, 4us, 4y, 4uy, 4.0, 4.0f, 4I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong set of characters.

I had to replace

> ''

with

> ``

Comment: If this answered your question, you should mark it as answered. That's perfectly OK to do, even if when you're answering your own question. You may even get a badge for it :)